# how can i include phpmailer 5.2 using composer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, autoload, psr-4

I'm trying to instantiate the PHP mailer class which i've installed using composer. The class is located in vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php

```
-Project
  -src
      -SmtpHandler.php
  -vendor
     -phpmailer
         -phpmailer
            class.phpmailer.php
  index.php
```

I'm trying to load this class inside SmtpHandler as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Fusion;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
class SmtpHandler {

var $mail;

function __construct () {
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
```

my composer.json file is autoloading my php classes like so:

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         "Fusion\\": "src"
    }

},
```

when $this->mail = new PHPMailer; is called, i recieve an error **Fatal error: Class 'Fusion\PHPMailer' not found in /var/www/proj/Project/src/SmtpHandler.php on line 8**

Do i need to use vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.phpmailer ? or am i using psr-4 wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For future reference (when it's released!), PHPMailer 5.4 declares a namespace and uses a PSR-4 naming layout.

Comment: This is over 3 months old, when i was fairly new to the site like i still am. There's no need to scout my profile to pick up on a mistake i made

Comment: Scouting isn't necessary. It shows up on this page.  You should accept the answer so others who come across this thread know it was correct and helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add after the namespace(`namespace Fusion;`) add
 `use PHPMailer as PHPMailer;` 
or when instanciating do the following: `new \PHPMailer;// instanciate from outside the current namespace`

This is because php tries to instanciate `Fusion\PHPMailer` from your current namespace.

Comment: fantastic, I'm new to using composer so this is all new teritory. But your answer did the trick.

Comment: Does this apply to any dependcies such as the facebook sdk also? Or do they differ depending on each one?

Comment: If you declared your own namespace yes, you must add a backslash or define it wih `use` or instanciate the class with the namespace: `$fb = new Facebook\Facebook...`.
This is beacause Facebook sdk has `Facebook` as namespace as I read earlyer here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0)